# Shell arithmetic: referencing a variable without the leading $

Tags: bash, shell, variable, arithmetic

I was surprised to read this in the Bash manual, describing [Arithmetic Evaluation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic):

> Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax.

I tried it out, and indeed, `var` behaves the same as `$var`:

```
❯ var=9
❯ echo $(( var + 5 ))
14
❯ (( var < 10 )) && echo 'single digits!'
single digits!
```

Is it considered bad practice to do so? Is it portable to other shells, or is this a Bashism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not considered bad practice to not use `$` for variables inside of arithmetic evaluation. As far as portability, `((…))` in general is not POSIX, so it will not work in shells such as dash. It will work in zsh and ksh. On the other hand, `$((…))` is in POSIX and works in all modern sh-style shells.

Comment: Side note: most bashisms are copied from ksh.